# How to filter items in html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code in html

```js
function FilterCard(filter) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var classList = document.getElementsByClassName("collapse");
  if (filter === 'All') {
    for (let i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
      classList[i].className = "collapse show";
      var childCards = classList[i].firstElementChild.children;
      for (let j = 0; j < childCards.length; j++) {
        childCards[j].style.display = "inline-flex";
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
      if (classList[i].className === "collapse show") {
        var childCards = classList[i].firstElementChild.children;
        console.log(childCards);
        var count = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < childCards.length; j++) {
          var card = childCards[j].firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
          if (card.innerText !== filter) {
            childCards[j].style.display = "none";
            count++;
          } else {
            childCards[j].style.display = "inline-flex";
          }
        }
        if (count == childCards.length) {
          classList[i].className = "collapse";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  .card-body .card {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 18rem;
  }
  
  .card {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Filter Card
                </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="FilterCard('All')">All</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="FilterCard('Card1')">Card1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="FilterCard('Card2')">Card2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="FilterCard('Card3')">Card3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Collapsible Group Item #1
                        </button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card1</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card2</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            Collapsible Group Item #2
                        </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card3</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card1</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                            Collapsible Group Item #3
                        </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card1</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card3</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
              <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now what I want to do is filter the cards based on it's title i.e Card1 , Card2 and so on.
If the Collapsible Group is collapsed then the filter should not display the filtered content for that group.

For example if I have Collapsible Item #2 collapsed , and I select card3 as my filter , then I should only see Collapsible item 1 and 3 which contains only card3 visible if it has any , Collaspsible item#2 should remain collapsed.
If the expanded item , does not have that filter , than the item should automatically collapse.
How do I achieve this using Jquery or Javascript?

Comment: Is this the answer you would like to get? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try selecting items, collapsing others? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have added the code of what I have tried so far. It seems to work but now the issue I face is when I try to expand a collapsed item after applying filter , I do not see any thing in that expanded item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you have modifed your html since the last time**, i have worked on **your first version**.

you have added a filter function in your html code, this piece of code does the same thing: (except for All)

```
$("div.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item").on('click', function(){
  collapse($(this).text());
});
```

I have modified your code to generalize it: to hide an item, you have to remove the class `show` , but also add the class `collapsed` to the link button

```js
var cardsToHide=[];
var obj=[];

$("#dropdownMenuButton").on('click', function(){
  cardsToHide=[];obj=[];
  cardsToCollect();
  //console.log(obj);
});
$("div.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item").on('click', function(){
  collapse($(this).text());
});


function cardsToCollect(){
  $("button.btn-link[data-target^='#collapse']").each(function(){
    var o = {};
    var key = $(this).attr("data-target");
    o.hide = $(this).hasClass("collapsed") ? true : false;
    o[key]=[]; 
    $(this).closest('div[class="card"]').find('h5.card-title').each(function(){
     let v = $(this).text();
     o[key].push(v);
     if(o.hide && !cardsToHide.includes(v)) cardsToHide.push(v);
    });
    obj.push(o);    
  });
}

function collapse(txt){
  for(let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    if(obj[i].hide)continue;
    let nameofKey = Object.keys(obj[i])[1];

    let re = new RegExp("^.+\\[");
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj[i]).replace(re, '');

    if(json.includes(txt))continue;

    $("button.btn-link[data-target='" + nameofKey + "']").addClass("collapsed");
    $(nameofKey).removeClass("show");   
  }//for i
}
```

```html
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            .card-body .card {
                margin: 5px;
                width: 18rem;
            }
            .card {
                display: inline-flex;
                margin: 5px;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid text-center">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Filter Card
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Card1</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Card2</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Card3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="accordion">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Collapsible Group Item #1
                        </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
              
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title">Card1</h5>
                                  <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title">Card2</h5>
                                  <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            Collapsible Group Item #2
                        </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title">Card3</h5>
                                  <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title">Card1</h5>
                                  <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                            Collapsible Group Item #3
                        </button>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title">Card1</h5>
                                  <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <h5 class="card-title">Card3</h5>
                                  <p class="card-text">Card Content Goes Here</p>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link1</a>
                                  <a href="#" class="card-link">Link2</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

your code hides when collapsing, but when you click on the button to show item.. you have to trap the click on the button link to modify your css properties. ITs the reason using classes is easier

Comment: I tried this on my local but nothing is happening

Comment: have you tested my code here? the snippet is the copy of your first html.(no onclick to filter function).just open all items. If you select card2, item 2 and 3 collapse

Comment: I worked it out with a little help of your code and the some modifications by myself.